# Postgres order by condition when and then

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I want to sort records based on dynamic condition in postgres.
Have 'created' column (timestamp) in database, and 'type'(boolean) column.

Now I want to sort based on 'created' desc. if 'created' > date I am passing, else sort descending based on type,created.

below is my query:

```
.... order by case when created > '2020-09-14 10:00:00' then created end desc, case when created < '2020-09-14 10:00:00' then (type,created) end desc;
```

But it's not working.. I am getting 2nd case result first, and 1st case at the bottom.

Comment: What if one result row satisfies the condition and the other not? How do the rows compare?

Comment: I already have a where clause for that.. I just want to sort based on last N days desc, then remaining with type and created.

Comment: Your expression does not reflect what you've written in the text. Try `order by case when created > '2020-09-14 10:00:00' then null else "type" end, created desc nulls first`

Comment: Sorry, a typo. Should be `... order by case when created > '2020-09-14 10:00:00' then null else "type" end nulls first, created desc;`. This is literally "sort based on last N days desc, then remaining with type and created".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, that should be

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN created <= '2020-09-14 10:00:00
              THEN "type"
         END,
         created DESC
```